# How do I get user's current voice channel using discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make my bot join the voice channel I'm currently using, but I can't seem to find how to get the message author's current voice channel.

So far I've seen suggestions to use `message.member.voiceChannel` but it doesn't work, `message.member` has no `voiceChannel` attribute.

I'm looking for something that works like this:

```
async execute(interaction) {
  const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
    channelId: interaction.member.voiceChannel,
    guildId: interaction.guild.id,
    adapterCreator: interaction.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's [`message.member.voice.channel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=voice), not `voiceChannel`.

Even then, you don't provide an ID at `channelId: interaction.member.voice.channel`. The channel ID should be `interaction.member.voice.channel.id`:

```js
const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
  channelId: interaction.member.voice.channel.id,
  guildId: interaction.guild.id,
  adapterCreator: interaction.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
});
```

Comment: Perfect, worked like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

Use `interaction.member.voice.channel`, `interaction.guildId`, and `interaction.guild.voiceAdapterCreator`